# Problem with INNER JOIN query - very long executing

Tags: mysql

I observed a problem when I use INNER JOIN query. When I use query without INNER JOIN, all work very fast. When I add INNER JOIN, the query executes very long. It's my query:

```
SELECT
    component_offer_unconnected.id AS id,
    component_offer_unconnected.title AS NAME,
    component_offer_unconnected.ean AS ean,
    component_offer_unconnected.productCode AS productCode,
    component_offer_unconnected.tmpImg AS tmpImg,
    component_offer_unconnected.userAccountName AS userAccountName,
    component_offer_unconnected.userAccountId AS userAccountId,
    component_offer_unconnected.complete AS complete,
    component_offer_unconnected.active AS active,
    component_offer_unconnected.stockAvailable AS stockAvailable
FROM
    component_offer_unconnected
INNER JOIN products ON(
        (
            products.productCode = component_offer_unconnected.productCode AND component_offer_unconnected.productCode != ''
        ) AND(
            products.ean = component_offer_unconnected.ean AND component_offer_unconnected.ean != ''
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    component_offer_unconnected.id
DESC
```

Comment: The query has no filtering condition. It's retrieving the entire set of matching rows. What's the estimate size of the number of rows?

Comment: First table ~4000 rows, second ~5000 rows

Comment: I must show all rows from 'component_offer_unconnected' which ean and productCode cell exist in 'products'

Comment: How many rows in `component_offer_unconnected`?  How many rows in the resultset?

Comment: You should move the "filtering" (the two `!=` tests) out of the `ON` into the `WHERE`.  (This won't change the performance, but will make the query more readable.)

Comment: @RickJames "component_offer_unconnected" have ~4000 rows

Comment: @Mateusz - Does `products` have `INDEX(productCode, ean)` in that order?

Answer (score 0):

The query can benefit from the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on component_offer_unconnected (id, productCode, ean);

create index ix2 on products (productCode, ean);
```

If you can add them, the query could experience a performance improvement. If it doesn't please post the new execution plan.

Now, your query as it is, can potantially find multiple matches for each row. If you want each row to show up only once you can use `EXISTS` instead, as in:

```
SELECT
    id AS id,
    title AS NAME,
    ean AS ean,
    productCode AS productCode,
    tmpImg AS tmpImg,
    userAccountName AS userAccountName,
    userAccountId AS userAccountId,
    complete AS complete,
    active AS active,
    stockAvailable AS stockAvailable
FROM component_offer_unconnected u
WHERE u.productCode != ''
  AND u.ean != ''
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.productCode = u.productCode 
      AND p.ean = u.ean
  )
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Suggested improvement:  Pull the two !='s out and put them in the outer `WHERE`.  That will probably avoid some `EXIST` calls.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, of course. That can improve performance. How didn't I see it?

Comment: @RickJames Your query is not fast. I check my query and execute time is 9 sec. Yours query execute time are 16 sec

Comment: @Mateusz - Hmmm... Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...`